# Is this a case of the same person registering with a different name?

Tags: discussion

Doesn't it appear that the person who posted this question
[Is my manager's attitude discriminatory?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61355/is-my-managers-attitude-discriminatory)

also posted this question?
[How can I determine if my manager is harassing me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64855/what-exactly-is-harassmen)

And if the former was considered off-topic, shouldn't the latter be off-topic as well?

(Just trying to understand. I personally don't care either way.)

Comment: It's almost certainly the same person trying to ask his question again, maybe intentionally trying to bypass the fact that the original question was closed. Since the OP didn't return after asking, there's no point in guessing at intent or recovering the question in my opinion so I agree with the close votes.

Answer (score 6):

I made a pretty sweeping edit to hopefully:

1. Make the question on topic (and not a rant)
2. Avoid it being duplicated of the previous question, which basically was a rant